# save data to mongodb with post api

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

i have a post function in my api file. i want to save an email in mongodb database using this post request:

```
rest-api/emails?from="test@mail.com"&"to"="test@test.com"&subject="some subject"&content="some more content"&provider=sendgrid&success=false
```

i post method is like below :

```
.post((req, res)=>{

  db.models.Email.create({from:req.body.from ,
                          to: req.body.to,
                          subject: req.body.subject,
                          content: req.body.content,
                          success: req.body.success,
                          provider: req.body.provider}, (err, result)=>{
    if(err){
      handleErrors(res, err);
      console.log(`error in creating Email :${err}`)
    }else {
      console.log()
      res.json(result)
    }
  });
});
```

after this post request only `_id`, `success`,`provider` fields save in mongodb.
how can i fix this ?

EDIT:
i remove all " from post request but still not saving correctly:

```
localhost:3000/rest-api/emails?from=example@example.com&to=test@test.com&subject=somesubject&content=somemorecontent&provider=sendgrid&success=false
```

res:

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "599add615fcb202b34c6a13e",
    "success": false,
    "provider": "sendgrid"
}
```

EDIT:
model :

```
var ValidationError = mongoose.Error.ValidationError;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise ;

var validateEmail = function(email) {
    if (email) return validator.isEmail(email);
    return true;
}

var EmailSchema = new Schema({
      from: {type: String, maxlength:100},
      to: {type: String, maxlength:100},
      subject: {type: String},
      content: {type: String},
      provider: {type: String, maxlength: 30, required: false, default: "sendgrid"},
      sentdate: { type: Date },
      success: {type: Boolean, default: false}
});
EmailSchema.pre('save',(next)=>{
  // if(!this.sentdate){
  //   this.sentdate = Date.now();
  // }
  next();
});

EmailSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
var Email = mongoose.model('Email',EmailSchema);




module.exports ={
  models:{
    Email
  },
  url: 'mongodb://localhost/emilapp',
}
```

`req.body` console:
{}
req.body is empty!

Comment: Because you can't have `"` in your url
You need to send pure text value in your url, so remove every `"` and it should work

Comment: Can you edit the question by adding Email model and console.log of req.body?

Comment: @ArpitSolanki edited

Comment: your req.body is null that's why no value is being saved. See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` is meant to be used for post requests data whereas you are sending data as a GET request. Query strings sent to express server are stored in `req.query` object. You need to modify our code to something like below.

```
.post((req, res)=>{

  db.models.Email.create({from:req.query.from ,
                          to: req.query.to,
                          subject: req.query.subject,
                          content: req.query.content,
                          success: req.query.success,
                          provider: req.query.provider}, (err, result)=>{
    if(err){
      handleErrors(res, err);
      console.log(`error in creating Email :${err}`)
    }else {
      console.log()
      res.json(result)
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your you don't put " between strings. so the GET request should be like:

```
rest-api/emails?from=test@mail.com&to=test@test.com&subject=some 
subject&content=some more content&provider=sendgrid&success=false
```